# Get event from inner observable

Tags: http, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

```ts
public testFunction(name: string, model: string): Observable<any> {
       return this.doSomething(name, model)
              .flatMap((result: any) => {
                   return this.doSomethingElse()... // returning an Observable<any>
               });
}
```

That `doSomething` is a HTTP call, actually returning an Observable by itself.
Here is were i call that method:

```ts
public foo () {
    this.testFunction(name, model)
                     .subscribe(
                     (result) => {
                         // do something
                     },
                     (error) => {
                         // do something wit the error
                     });
}
```

Problem is: how can i catch if the `doSomething` HTTP call went good or bad from within `foo`?
I do not want to use a Subject or Behaviour subject since testFunction is part of a service and foo is on a component. I mean, don't want to add a *"superstructure"* to achieve it.

Comment: By "within `foo`" you mean before the method returns?

Comment: Exactly, as soon as the doSomething call went well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check my solution on:

[Notify from inner flatMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992711/notify-from-inner-flatmap/41146245#41146245)

Quite simple and you don't have to merge different observables.

Comment: Thanks, that looks quite nice!

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution: by splitting that big observable i can handle two differents `onNext` instead of just one. 
This allows me to know when the first method (`doSomething`) ends.
Here a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/crWpj8deQzePCrTtYz6k?p=preview

```
public testFunction(name: string, model: string): Observable<any> {
   let obs1 = this.doSomething(name, model);
   let obs2 = obs1.flatMap((data) => { 
                 return this.doSomethingElse() //[...]
           });
   let merge = Observable.merge(obs1, obs2);
   return merge  
}
```

```ts
public foo () {
    this.testFunction(name, model)
                     .subscribe(
                     (result) => {
                         // 1 - Obs1 next
                         // 2 - Obs2 next
                     },
                     (error) => {
                         // do something wit the error
                     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code does exactly what you want. If an onError is raised in DoSomethingElse it is emitted to the main stream and will end up in your subscription onError in the foo() method.

If you want to have more control over how your succes/error is propagated you could also do something like this:

```
public testFunction(name: string, model: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.doSomething(name, model)
    .flatMap((result: any) => this.doSomethingElse()
        .map((doSomethingElseResult:any) => ({ result:'succes', data: doSomethingElseResult })
        .catch(err => Rx.Observable.just({ result: 'do-something-else-error', error: err }))
    )
    .catch(err => Rx.Observable.just({ result: 'do-something-error', error:err });
}
```

This will convert all errors to onNext values which have a type for you to handle upon if the type is `do-something-else-error`

Comment: Hi Marks, thanks for the reply. That's not exactly what i'm trying to achieve: whenever i subscribe to testFunction i want to be noticed if doSomething went well. In my subscribe i'm receiving ONLY the onNext event obtained at the very end of testFunction and not the one on doSomething. No problem if i have to handle errors et similia btw.

Comment: Im trying to understand your requirements. Do you also need the output of the `doSomethingElse`? Or are you only interested in the first result