# Notify from inner flatMap

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Here a quite complex sample:

Main:

```
this.runInstructionAndGetResult().subscribe({
      next: val => console.log(`NEXT VALUE: ${val}`),
      error: val => console.log(`ERROR VALUE: ${val}`),
      complete: val => console.log(`COMPLETE`)
    });
```

Observables:

```
public runInstructionAndGetResult(): Observable<string> {
    return this.runAnInstruction()
        .flatMap((data) => {
            console.info("flatMap of runAnInstruction:", data);
            return this.getInstructionExecutionStatusInPolling()
                .filter(data => data != "Polling")
                .take(1)
                .flatMap((data) => {
                    console.info("flatMap of getInstructionExecutionStatusInPolling:", data);
                    return this.getInstructionResult();
                }).map((data) => {
                    console.info("Map of getInstructionResult:", data);
                    return data;
                });
        });
  }

  public runAnInstruction(): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.of("StartRun");
  }

  public getInstructionResult(): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.of("FinalResult");
  }

  public getInstructionExecutionStatusInPolling(): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.interval(1000)
        .concatMap(data => {
            return this.getInstructionExecutionStatus();
        });
  }

  public getInstructionExecutionStatus(): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.of("Polling", "Terminate");
  }
```

Here plunk:
https://plnkr.co/edit/c1cahMtVARQnLgnHWlEe?p=preview

Main problem is that i just would like to be notify about "evolution" of inner stream outside.

**Right now we have "next" event on main only when all inner flatMap are completed.**

**How to get notify?** How can i emit explicit values to main stream for example during polling?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more explicit what result you want to get? Or what output you want to see in console. I don't understand what's this all supposed to do.

Comment: @martin I just would like to have on main subscribe a next call with for example "StartRun" data or "Terminate" data.

Comment: So if I understand this correcty: You want to receive 2 next-calls from a stream that you start with only 1 datum - in that case you should take a look at the concat-operators, or try something like `this.runInstructionAndGetResult().startWith("StartRun").subscribe...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to share.

Here plunker updated:

https://plnkr.co/edit/c1cahMtVARQnLgnHWlEe?p=preview

Basically i create a simple observable using : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/create.md

then i call programmatically next method and complete finally:

```
 public runInstructionAndGetResult(): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.create((ops)=> {
      ops.next(1);
      this.runAnInstruction()
        .concatMap((data) => {
            ops.next(2);
            console.info("flatMap of runAnInstruction:", data);
            return this.getInstructionExecutionStatusInPolling()
                .filter(data => data != "Polling")
                .take(1)
                .concatMap((data) => {
                    ops.next(3);
                    console.info("flatMap of getInstructionExecutionStatusInPolling:", data);
                    return this.getInstructionResult();
                }).map((data) => {
                    console.info("Map of getInstructionResult:", data);
                    ops.next(4);
                    ops.complete();
                    return data;
                });
        }).subscribe();
        });
  }
```